# getting 403 forbidden when accessing jenkins web administration site

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am running jenkins master in docker container on digital ocean. When accessing web admin portal on http://x.x.x.x:8080 it returns 403 forbidden so I can't login.

When accessing same container hosted on localhost as http://localhost:8080 everything is fine, I get login page.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Hi, I guess you should open that port in the digital ocean firewall

Comment: it is open. jenkins responds with 403.

Comment: Can we see the Dockerfile and commands you used?

Comment: docker run --name jenkins --net host -d --restart unless-stopped -v /var/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home  -u 0:0 jenkins/jenkins:lts

Comment: runnig it as root

Answer (score 0):

As it happens, asking this question made me realize what the problem might be. It's that I run jenkins container as root. When running as a user with uid 1000 it works.

So, to get it working:

- Create user 'jenkins' on docker host with UID:GID 1000:1000.
- When running jenkins container, mount /var/jenkins_home from container to
  jenkins users' home dir. In my case it's /home/jenkins.

Comment: Why did you need to run it with UDI 1000?